# How to show selected tick labels in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scale

I'm using the d3 library to create a gantt chart. So far i have done something similar to this image:

[image]

However, as you can notice, on the hour axis the far left and far right  12AM labels are running out of the box. So, i'd like to know if there is a way to start the time ticks from 2AM and end in 10PM?

I define the hour axis like that:

```
  x1HourAxis
    .ticks(d3.time.hours, 2)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%I %p'));
```

i want to keep this configuration, but as i said, i'd like to start the time from 2AM then 4AM... until 10AM, so that i don't have this bad visual effect on the chart

Answer (score 1):

do you have more code? it's hard to tell what is going on but you can try:

```
x1HourAxis
.ticks(d3.time.hours, 2)
.tickFormat(d3.time.format('%I %p'))
.tickSize(some value here for major tick size, some value here for minor tick size, 0);
```

setting the last parameter in axis.tickSize() to 0 will suppress the end ticks.

see: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes

Comment: Will setting tick size to zero successfully suppress tick labels as well?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to explicitly set the tick values that you want to display. You can do this with `axis.tickValues([values])`

Your axis, in your particular case, would be `x1HourAxis`, and I believe that `values` would be `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22]`, but you might need to either give them as time values (e.g. 2:00 PM) or else in ms values. I haven't tried explicitly setting values for time scales, so I'm not entirely sure what the convention is.

Comment: not sure you can do that for time scales, i think it only works with quantitative scales; I'll give it a go

Comment: axis.tickValues works for quantitative scales, but not for time scales.